# How to upload multiple files using Laravel and Vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm new on Vue and Laravel and trying to upload multiple files but don't get those files to database. I already know on v-model or type doesn't work on file input. I'm trying on my best, but i have no idea to make it work.
Here is my vue component

```
<v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" class="d-flex flex-column">
          <label for="" class="font-weight-bold pt-1">Attach Document</label>
                <input type="file" @change="uploadFile($event)" class="quotationCsv">
        </v-col>
</v-row>
<script>


    export default {
        methods: {
            uploadFile(event) {
                const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/product/add_adjustment';
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
                let config = {
                    header: {
                        'content-Type' : 'image/*, application/pdf'
                    }
                }
                this.$axios.$post(url,data,config)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And, Here is my Laravel

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'file' => 'nullable',
    ]);

    $quotation = new Quotation();

    $quotation->file = $request ->file;

    return response()->json(['created' => true]);
}
```

Comment: on your controller try first line return `return $request;` you have the response? on your console.log

Comment: I would personally advise you to save the file in your laravel "storage" folder and just save the path in the database!

Comment: @Snoxik Do you have any simple because i have no idea.